# Difference between value and avg(value)

Tags: mysql, sql

I wonder if it is possible to make query like following one.

I have a table that contains `id`  and `value`. 
Exapmle:

```
 table EXAMPLE
|id        |  value     |
|        1 |          65|
|        2 |          13|
|        3 |          22|
```

What I want is to make query that returns the set like this:

```
|id        |  value     | average | difference|   
|        2 |          13|     33.3|       20.3|
|        3 |          22|     33.3|       11.3|
```

The question is how to deal with different column ?

And one more question:
 How to include in the set  only values, that are less or great then average ,

```
SELECT id,
       value,
       (SELECT AVG(value) FROM EXAMPLE ) as average
having 
       value <  average.
```

The reason i am using `having` instead of `where` is that `where` is executing before select and therefore i cant use average in it (average is computed in the select phase of query execution).

I also suspect that I am calculating AVG(value) not only once, but for every row in the table.
Am i right ?  If i am, that is pretty bad and  it is surely not what i wanted.

Please get some light for me on the MySQL execution sequence of subqueries or share some links for this theme. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am terrible sorry. That was from the first version of question. Edited. Nevertheless I don't think it is important in context of question. I hope I am able to be understood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to calculate the overall average separately and force a cross join:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f51e/4)

```
select
    id,
    value,
    avgValue,
    avgValue - value as Diff
from
    table1
  cross join
    ( 
      select
          avg(value) as AvgValue
      from
          table1
    ) t2
where
    value < avgValue
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I spend hours looking for how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do it.  You need to group in order to do you aggregate functions.

```
SELECT id, value, (SELECT AVG(value) FROM example GROUP BY id) AS average,
       average - value AS diff
FROM example
GROUP BY id
HAVING value < average;
```

Comment: If yoy group by id, you get the average per id. That is not what is wanted. Also, your group by is normally illegal (since all non-aggregate columns should be in a group by). That said, the OP also has an invalid query, missing even the basic `FROM` clause...

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, value, (select avg(value) from EXAMPLE ) as average, 
   (select avg(value) from EXAMPLE ) - value as difference
   from EXAMPLE ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This also does the trick

```
select id, value,
       (select avg(Value) from table1) as avg,
       (select avg(Value) from table1) - value as Diff
from table1 having Diff > 0
```

Comment: In this case `avg` is calculated only once or every time the new row selected ?

Comment: Good question, I think that depends on the optimizer. It should be able to recognize that the average selection is constant for all rows, and thus calculate it once, but I wouldn't dare to predict whether that is true for a specific dbms or not :)